# Searching a List of Lists for 2 Conditions

Tags: python, list

So I have a list of lists that contains integers and I want return how many row/lists within it have the numbers 5 and 8 appear two of more times. I have written the following code which logically makes sense to me but it returns 0. Any help would be appreciated.

Output im looking for is 3 since lists 0,2, and 5 have the numbers 5 and 8 appear two of more times.

```
    five_count = 0
    eight_count = 0
    row_count = 0

    test =[[5,0,5,0,0,0,8,0,8,0,0],
    [1,1,5,98,5,5,13,13,6,7,8],
    [5,0,5,0,0,0,8,0,8,0,0],
    [1,1,5,5,56,5,13,13,6,7,8],
    [1,9,5,5,25,5,13,19,6,7,8],
    [5,0,5,0,0,0,8,0,8,0,0]
    ]

    for list in test:
        for num in list:
             if(num == 5):
                 five_count=+1
             elif(num == 8):
                 eight_count=+1
                 if(five_count >= 2 and eight_count >= 2):
                      row_count=+1

      print(row_count)
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should avoid naming variables in ways the mask python builtins. For example, naming a variable `list` means you can no longer use the `list()` built-in method.

Comment: Why is your `if five_count...` indented _inside_ `elif num==8`? You want to check if the count exceeds 2 _after_ you have tested all elements in a row, don't you?

Comment: Other than the `+= 1` typos, you also need to reset `five_count` and `eight_count` to zero for each row. [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension, and `list.count(num)` function which returns no. of times `num` occurs in the `list` -

```
test =[[5,0,5,0,0,0,8,0,8,0,0],
    [1,1,5,98,5,5,13,13,6,7,8],
    [5,0,5,0,0,0,8,0,8,0,0],
    [1,1,5,5,56,5,13,13,6,7,8],
    [1,9,5,5,25,5,13,19,6,7,8],
    [5,0,5,0,0,0,8,0,8,0,0]
    ]

# if your are interested in only the count of rows
row_count = sum(1 for l in test if l.count(5) >= 2 and l.count(8) >= 2)
print(row_count)   # prints 3
```

```
# if you want all the indexes where the condition is satisfied
indexes = [ind for ind, l in enumerate(test) if l.count(5) >= 2 and l.count(8) >= 2]
print(indexes)     # prints [0, 2, 5]
```

modifying your code in place, note the

1. Use of `+=` instead of the incorrect `=+`
2. indentation of the `if (five_count >= 2 and eight_count >= 2)`
3. setting the `five_count` and `eight_count` to `0` for each list so that we starting counting again from `0` -

```
test =[[5,0,5,0,0,0,8,0,8,0,0],
[1,1,5,98,5,5,13,13,6,7,8],
[5,0,5,0,0,0,8,0,8,0,0],
[1,1,5,5,56,5,13,13,6,7,8],
[1,9,5,5,25,5,13,19,6,7,8],
[5,0,5,0,0,0,8,0,8,0,0]
]

row_count = 0

for list in test:
    five_count, eight_count = 0, 0
    for num in list:
        if (num == 5):
            five_count += 1
        elif (num == 8):
            eight_count += 1
    print(five_count, eight_count)
    if (five_count >= 2 and eight_count >= 2):
        row_count += 1

print(row_count)  # prints 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you update the counters.

```
five_count =+ 1
```

Set the counter to 1 no matter what.
The correct syntax for your need is

```
five_count += 1
```

Comment: _Technically_, `five_count=+1` is still correct _syntax_, it just doesn't do what OP wants to do.

Comment: Thanks :) I made it clear for what I meant